# Complicated MySQL Select query

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Here is my table layout:

[image: Screenshot of database layout]

**What I would like to do:**

1. Count the number of `votes` for each `songID` in a particular room (passed in as a parameter).
2. Find out if the userID has at least one vote for a song in a particular room. UserID is also passed in as a parameter.
3. An extension of the two above. If there are no votes for a song, I would like to return 0 for those entries.

**What I have:**

```
select a.SongID, count(*) as voteCount, b.UserID 
  from votes a left join votes b 
    on a.songID = b.songID 
   and b.RoomID = 178 
   and b.UserID = 71 
 where a.RoomID = 178 
 group by a.SongID, b.UserID
```

(feel free to use those `RoomID` and `UserID` numbers in examples)

The above SQL statement does 1 and 2 but not 3.  Is there any way to extend it to do 3?  It would be nice to get all this done in a single query.  Right now it returns all songs that have a vote, the number of votes and if the `UserID` in question has voted (null otherwise).  Thanks in advance.

Just to clarify a bit, currently, this statement will only output songs with entries in the `votes` table, I'm trying to modify it to include songs that do not have entries in the `votes` table (that is, to include all songs in `Select SongID from songs where RoomID = 178`).  Also keeping in mind everything is room-specific. Songs are matched to a certain room by their `SongID`.

Here is my song table for example:

```
+--------+--------+
| SongID | RoomID |
+--------+--------+
|   2835 |    178 |
|   2836 |    178 |
|   2837 |    178 |
|   2838 |    178 |
|   2839 |    178 |
|   2840 |    178 |
|   2841 |    178 |
|   2842 |    178 |
|   2843 |    178 |
|   2844 |    178 |
|   2845 |    178 |
|   2846 |    178 |
|   2847 |    178 |
|   2848 |    178 |
+--------+--------+
```

Here is the votes:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| SongID | UserID | RoomID |
+--------+--------+--------+
|   2835 |     71 |    178 |
|   2836 |     71 |    178 |
|   2837 |     71 |    178 |
|   2838 |     71 |    178 |
|   2839 |     71 |    178 |
|   2840 |     71 |    178 |
|   2841 |     71 |    178 |
|   2842 |     71 |    178 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

And finally, the result of the query I have so far:
Only the first 7 songs have votes and only those are returned. I would like to modify this query to include ALL songs that are in the room, even if they have no votes (and return the vote count as 0 or null).

```
+--------+-----------+--------+
| SongID | voteCount | UserID |
+--------+-----------+--------+
|   2835 |         1 |     71 |
|   2836 |         1 |     71 |
|   2837 |         1 |     71 |
|   2838 |         1 |     71 |
|   2839 |         1 |     71 |
|   2840 |         1 |     71 |
|   2841 |         1 |     71 |
+--------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: can you put your desired output

Comment: How `RoomID` in `songs` related to `RoomID` in `votes`?

Comment: `RoomID` in `song`s and `RoomID` in `votes` are both foreign keys to the original `RoomID` in `rooms`

Comment: I understand that. The question is why do you have `RoomID` in songs if a song can be in several rooms? Can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your query might look like this

```
SELECT s.SongID, 
       COALESCE(v.allVotes, 0) allVotes, 
       COALESCE(v.userVotes, 0) userVotes
  FROM songs s LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT SongId, 
         COUNT(*) allVotes,
         SUM(CASE WHEN UserID = 71 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) userVotes
    FROM votes
   WHERE RoomID = 178 
   GROUP BY SongID
) v 
    ON s.songID = v.songID 
 WHERE s.RoomID = 178
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4668/2)** demo